# Modify displayed tableview data for iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new in iphone development.I have one view controller which contains tableview and for custom cell there is uitableviewCell which contains favorite button like as twitter favorite button.I am using AFNETWORKING for sending get and post request and response is comming in json format.After parse json i am displaying json in tableview.The json which is i am getting like below

```
{ "user_id" = 328; "user_name" = "ios.dev";"user_lname" = "imac";}
{ "user_id" = 318; "user_name" = "ios.dev1";"user_lname" = "imac1";}
{ "user_id" = 358; "user_name" = "ios.dev2";"user_lname" = "imac2";}
{ "user_id" = 328; "user_name" = "ios.dev3";"user_lname" = "imac3";}
{ "user_id" = 338; "user_name" = "ios.dev4";"user_lname" = "imac4";}
```

There is one favorite button on tableview cell. When i am clicking on button some response is comming from server.Suppose i am clicking on first cell the post request will go using that cell userid and new response will come.Now my problem is how to display new json data in current cell and also i want to modify the other cell data without reloading tableview with new data.Example suppose i receive response

```
{ "user_id" = 328; "user_name" = "iphonefamily";"user_lname" = "iphoneprogram";}
```

Now i want to search entire tableview whose cell user_id with newresponse user_id and want to replace those cell data with new data response.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
NSArray *tweets=responseobject;
placesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in tweets) {


                TweetData *tweetData=[[TweetData alloc]initWithDictionary:dictionary];
                [placesArray addObject:tweetData];

            }


            [tableview reloadData];
        }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    TweetCell *cell=[tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TweetCell"];

    cell.tweet=[placesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.delegate=self;

   /// cell.tweet=placesArray[indexPath.row];




    return cell;
}
```

This is the code which is i am using for displaying data. and inside the custom cell `- (IBAction)onFavorite:(id)sender {}` 
method.

Comment: I guess calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` will work for you.

Comment: but i don't want to reload my tableview

Comment: You can reload a particular cell as well, which one is updated. Until you update, the data will not get reflected on UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary for key userId and indexPath as values.
Then when you get data from server, find the corresponding Index path from dictionary, put it in an array and use 
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:<#(NSArray *)#> withRowAnimation:<#(UITableViewRowAnimation)#>]

Answer (score 0):

In the method where you get updated data do this:

```
__block NSInteger indexOfElement;
[placesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(TweetData *tweetData, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (tweetData.userId == newTweetData.userId) {
        indexOfElement = idx;
        stop = YES;
    }
}];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexOfElement inSection:0];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Where newTweetData is the object with new data.

Change the type of placesArray to NSMutableArray. To replace old object do

```
[placesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexOfElement withObject:newTweetData];
```

Comment: Sir , indexOfElement = idx; showing an error  "variable is not assignable (missing_block type specifier)" and how to  replace perticular index if match found.I am getting response in nsarray. - (IBAction)onFavorite:(id)sender {
    
        [[TwitterClient sharedInstance]post:followerurl param:paraMtrs completion:^(NSArray *tweets, NSError *error) {
            ];} please suggest